# Validate form before doPost() is called?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Apps Script application, containing a form with a submit button, and I am trying to do some validation on the data in the form when the submit button is clicked.

The problem is that the form is gone by the time `doPost()` is called, and it is painful to re-create it in case validation fails.

Is there any way to do server-side validation **before** `doPost()` is called?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [validators](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/uiapp#Validators) to do some basic checks.
Another possibility is to use a 'normal' `doGet()` function and 'normal' buttons that can work as a *multi step* confirmation with full data validation before the data is really processed. The only limitation is that you cannot use the file upload feature outside of a doPost structure but this strictly depends on what you need or not.

[Here is a small example](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxSg_IulNQmGrukomzJ2BxUhKYaNtJLKbe7tt4V1kA0WrxQouc/exec) of a multi step confirmation in a form. And [the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AshxSsxZv3fndF9iTThCbUFyczd2M3hyY2pKZUZtZGc#gid=0) with the script and data.